# Grape - Mounting V1 inside V2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I using [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) to create API and I have issue : How I can mounting V1 inside V2

/api/v1/users.rb

```
module API
  module V1
    class Users < Grape::API
      resource :users do
        desc "Timeline" do
        end
        get :time_line do
         {status: true, version: 'v1'}
        end

        desc "Timeline" do
        end
        get :profile do
         {status: true, profile: {email: "julian@vinova.sg"}, version: 'v1'}
        end
      end
    end
 end
end
```

/api/v1/base.rb

```
module API
  module V1
    class Base < Grape::API
        prefix 'api'
        format :json
        version 'v1', using: :path


        mount API::V1::Users
        
        add_swagger_documentation \
          api_version: 'v1'
    end
  end
end
```

/api/v2/users.rb

```
module API
  module V2
    class Users < Grape::API
      resource :users do
        desc "Timeline" do
       end
       params do
        use :pagination
       end
       get :time_line do
        {status: true, version: 'v2'}
       end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

/api/v2/base.rb

```
module API
  module V2
    class Base < Grape::API
        prefix 'api'
        format :json
        version 'v2',  using: :path
        
        
        mount API::V2::Users
        
        add_swagger_documentation \
          api_version: 'v2'
     end
  end
end
```

/api/base.rb

```
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
    mount ::API::V1::Base
    mount ::API::V2::Base
  end
end
```

I want :profile(/api/v2/users/profile) to also be implemented in V2 without having to repeat the code. Now, any suggestions to do that ?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to mount V1 inside of V2?

Comment: It's a long shot, but have you tried mounting the `/api/v1/users/profile` file into the `/api/v2/base.rb`. Try adding `mount ::API::V1::UserProfile` after the `mount API::V2::Users` line in `/api/v2/base.rb`. This would require your User Profile code to be in a separate file.